# "Unauthorized operation" error when installing Express Edition

Tags: sql-server-2008, windows-7-x64

Microsoft Outlook 2010 with Business Contact Manager worked on my Vista laptop but, laptop died. Now, have Windows 7 Ultimate x64 tower since November. Loaded Office 2010 x86 just fine but, trying to install BCM, failed to install SQL Server Express.

So, now I can't get SQL Server 2008 to install; the Engine, that is, all supporting files install fine. I read that if you can install SQL Server 2008 with the `ID=MSSMLBIZ`, BCM will pass over the server install, and continue with install. I read that the issue may be SQL Server x86 on Win 7 x64. So, I tried SQL Server x64. Every time I get an `Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation`.

Install always fails at step `SqlBrowserConfigAction_install_ConfigNonRC_Cpu32`. So, ran as Admin, from Admin log-in, from the root directory in the Admin log-in, changing permissions on the Security Registry KEY, turned off firewall, all suggestions still failed.

Coincidentally, I have an Update for Windows 7 for x64-based systems (KB2732487) that has failed to install, as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think your Windows 7 is not proper installed, perhaps while installing Windows Updates.
But as for the

> SqlBrowserConfigAction_install_ConfigNonRC_Cpu32

I dont understand: ConfigNonRC , in Microsoft terms stands the RC for Release Candidate.

If i was you i should try this:

1. Open CMD as Admin
2. Typ: "sfc /scannow"
3. When that's ready your pc may restart.
4. Now at CMD typ: "sfc /verifyonly"

If it shows any errors, try "sfc /scannow" again.

If it does not show any errors, try to install Windows Updates. All of them.

If this works, delete all existing SQL apps. And install the Core first.

If the updates can't install, You can try to re-install Windows 7 what i basically should not do and just use MySQL. A lot faster & reliable these days.

I hope this will fix your problems!

Comment: I can't comment on the rest of your answer, but installing MySQL is not a solution if the OP wants to install SQL Server. In this specific case it seems to be a requirement for BCM, but even more generally it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Ran Scannow as requested, twice. No errors. Ran Windows update install successful but, failed on reboot and windows reverted back to pre-update. Time to reinstall Windows, I think. And, yes, SQL is required by BCM and MySQL is not an option.

Comment: Hmm, i think your windows is corrupt. If i was you, i should install windows again. Maby on an other partition, or run VMWare. I dont see the what kind of problem there is with windows update. I had this event more then 8 times on my pc, all with a fresh install of windows 7. I must say that Windows 8 fixed the problem for me ;)